# SQLite and Swift - Using a .db file from assets

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I dragged my ".db" file into my project.. and my assets.

let db = try Connection("architect.db")

Prints this error to console:

> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.354630-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f]
>
> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.354718-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   os_unix.c:43353: (0) open(//architect.db) - Undefined error: 0
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)
>
> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.363920-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f]
>
> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.363993-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   os_unix.c:43353: (0) open(//architect.db) - Undefined error: 0
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)
>
> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.365709-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f]
>
> 2020-01-30 23:21:16.365758-0800 architect[398:88870] [logging-persist]
>   os_unix.c:43353: (0) open(//architect.db) - Undefined error: 0
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)

I see tons of answers to this question for Android, but none for iOS.

Comment: Did you check this part of the SQLite.swift documentation [Read-Only Databases](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#read-only-databases) ?

Comment: Did you really search and not find anything? Try searching (google or whatever) for `ios swift sqlite database in assets` ... Lots of answers / tutorials / articles / etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:
let db = try Connection(Bundle.main.path(forResource: "architect", ofType: "db")!)